# Change placeholder character in Laravel Translations System

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I would like to change the Laravel placeholder char in Language System but I don't know if I can do that. Right now, in Laravel 5.1, when you want to add a placeholder in a language file you must do it like this:

```
return [
  'comment_anonymous_or_login' => 'Hi! My name is :name how are you?'
]
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
return [
  'comment_anonymous_or_login' => 'Hi! My name is {!name!} how are you?'
]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: When we give the translations to translators they don't understand fine the way replacement works and if in a text I want to include a colon, then how does a translator know weather it is a placeholder or a char?

Comment: If the colon is 
**immediatly** after a word `:likethis` then it's a placeholder, otherwise not. For example this word is not a placeholder `: thisisnotaplaceholder`.

Comment: For people who is used to see code, it has sense, but for people that just translate text is not that easy and I think that another char would make their job easier, so I want to change it.

Comment: As far as I know, Laravel does not support it natively. You should override [this function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php#L131) and modify it as you want.

Comment: I have answered the question properly if you feel like accepting it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Laravel does not support natively changing the placeholder character through settings.

However you could override the framework's class ([Illuminate\Translation\Translator](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php#L131)) and modify the function.